# Автоматический перезапуск скрипта

Tags: bash

Имеется небольшой скрипт, написанный на Python. Нужно сделать так, чтобы он перезапускался каждую минуту. Пытался написать программу на bash, но ничего не получилось.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 python3 code.py
 sleep 60
 SIGKILL
done
```

Comment: А что не получилось? Дополните вопрос кнопкой "править".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так, чтобы он перезапускался каждую минуту.

Надо запускать с помощью системного сервиса *cron*. Вы же под люнихом работаете?

Для этого надо добавить строчку в файл *crontab*. Если этот скрипт будете запускать только Вы, то можно ограничится локальной таблицей *crontab*. Если же скрипт нужен для работы системы в целом, то надо использовать глобальную таблицу.

Что конкретно нужно писать в таблицу, прочитайте в *man 5 crontab*.  Скорее всего, дополнительная строчка будет иметь вид:

```
* * * * 1-5 /home/taiko/scripts.sh
```

Что означает: запускать скрипт */home/taiko/scripts.sh* каждую минуту с понедельника по пятницу.

Как именно надо редактировать этот  файл - прочитайте в *man 1 crontab*.

PS. Не моё, разумеется дело, но я шибко подозреваю, что речь идёт о типичном виндовозном приёме передачи информации между двумя программами, когда одна программа пишет данные в некоторые файлы в фиксированном каталоге, а другая (потребитель) регулярно просматривает этот каталог.

Поверьте, это самоё плохое решение. В Linux для этого есть гораздо более подходящие средства.

Comment: Да нет. Я пишу бота для Telegram на Python, а из-за того, что у библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI есть какие-то проблемы, то мои мои боты часто вылетают. Появляется неизвестная ошибка, решить которой я долго не мог. Потом в голову пришла идея решить проблему таким способом и я попытался написать скрипт на bash, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: @АрсенийТайко *мои мои боты часто вылетают* Я занимался разработкой устойчивых систем и могу подсказать стандартный путь решения этой проблемы. 1) Вы запускаете "стартёр". 2) Стартёр входит в бесконечный цикл 3) Внутри цикла стартёр запускает Вашу основную программу (fork) и ждёт (waitpid) её завершения. 4) По завершению основной программы - переход на начало цикла.

Comment: Я попробовал `crontab`, но при перезагрузки процесс не убивается и скрипт запускается повторно. Это вызывает ошибку, которая останавливает всех ботов.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно питоновский скрипт запускать в фоне, чтобы bash-скрипт продолжил свое выполнение.
Попробуйте так:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 python3 code.py &
 PID=$!
 sleep 60
 kill -SIGKILL $PID
done
```